# Absolute value of difference between expected values of two distributions and total variation

Tags: probability, proof-verification, inequality, probability-distributions, total-variation

I'm trying to prove following inequality.
For any probability distribution $P$ и ${Q}$ on $U$ and function $f(x): U \rightarrow [0; B]$ it is true that:
$$ |E_{\tilde P}[f(x)] − E_{\tilde Q}[f(x)]| \leq \frac B2 ||P − Q||$$
where $||\cdot||$ – total variation distance. 
I can use discrete distributions for proof.

What I have for now:
$$|\sum_{x\in U} f(x)(p_P(x) - p_Q(x))| \leq \frac B2||P - Q||$$
Denote $g(x) = \frac{f(x)}{B}$, then $g: U \rightarrow [0;1]$:
$$|\sum_{x\in U} g(x)(p_P(x) - p_Q(x))| \leq \frac 12\sum_{x\in U: p_P(x)>p_Q(x)}[p_P(x) - p_Q(x)]$$
Now open the summation on the left with the consideration that difference of measures can be positive or negative:
$$|\sum_{p_P(x)>p_Q(x)} g(x)(p_P(x) - p_Q(x)) - \sum_{p_Q(x)>p_P(x)} g(x)(p_Q(x) - p_P(x))| \leq $$

$$\leq \sum_{p_P(x)>p_Q(x)} g(x)(p_P(x) - p_Q(x)) \leq \sum_{p_P(x)>p_Q(x)} (p_P(x) - p_Q(x))$$

What I did wrong?

Comment: I'm using [Remark 4.3](https://books.google.ru/books?id=6Cg5Nq5sSv4C&lpg=PP1&hl=ru&pg=PA48#v=onepage&q&f=false) in second line of proof.